# Инициализация массива. Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу

Tags: массивы, функции, инициализация

Прошу подсказать как правильно инициализировать массив в моем случае?

```
//usinglib.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MassivFromMaxValue.h"
using namespace std;
const int n = 6, m = 4;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int * mas[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "Введите элемент массива [" << i  << "][" << j  << "]: ";
            cin >> *mas[i][j]; //Падает здесь. Из-за не инициализированного массива как я понимаю
        }
    }
    cout << "Исходный массив:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "    " << *mas[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "Итоговый массив:" << endl;
    int* target;
    target = fnMassivFromMaxValue(*mas,n,m);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "    " << *mas[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

На всякий случай функция:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "MassivFromMaxValue.h"
using namespace std;
int* fnMassivFromMaxValue(int * m[], unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
{
    int* b = new int[cols];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) //Заполняем массив b
        b[i] = *max_element(m[i], m[i] + cols);
    return b;
}
```

Вот так не подходит

```
int * mas = new int*[n][m];
```

Очень прошу подсказать.
Спасибо!

Comment: Разобрался сам. ```int** mas = new int* [m]; // Создаем и инициализируем массив
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
        mas[count] = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам.
Нужно было следующее:

```
int** mas = new int* [m]; // Создаем и инициализируем массив
    for (int count = 0; count < n; count++)
        mas[count] = new int[n];
```

И, естественно удалить все указатели (*) в main